# log4j.properties not being picked in Maven based Application

Tags: maven, log4j

I have searched enough for the below question but could not find the appropriate answer. I would be glad if you can provide me a link if the question already exists.

I am new to Maven and I have created a Maven based application integrated with Hibernate.

### Question:

I have a log4j.properties file in "src/java/resources" I have created a Logger instance in one of my classes and tried to print logs however the logs do not get printed on to the console.

Note: I have given the stdout as logs output location.

Comment: I can see `maven` and `java` tag, can we have anything corresponding to these two in your question to make it clearer?

Comment: have a look at https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

Answer (score 1):

`src/java/resources/` sounds suspicious. The correct location for classpath resources is `src/main/resources/`. Put the `log4j.properties` there.

Additionally, it depends on the version you're using. `log4j.properties` is no longer supported in newer version. In case you use `log4j 2`, migrate to [`log4j2.xml`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html).

Comment: Yes you are right, I had a look at my application once again it is src/main/resources. Sorry for the mistake -  I already mentioned new to java :P. Can you suggest an answer in this case

Comment: @Balakrishna: Ok. Then it depends on the version you're using. `log4j.properties` is no longer supported in newer version. In case you use `log4j 2`, migrate to [`log4j2.xml`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html).